# footmisc's 'hang' option has no effect with polyglossia set to French

Tags: xetex, footnotes, languages, polyglossia, footmisc

I typeset a document with XeLaTeX and (partly) in French, and I want to use the `footmisc` package with the `hang` option (so that the footnote numbers hang on the left of the footnote content).

However, `\setmainlanguage{french}` breaks this, and the option has no effect any more — everything works fine with `\setmainlanguage{english}`, but the problem reappears if I add `\setotherlanguage{french}`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\footnote{\lipsum}.

\end{document}
```

This is the result I get:

[image: wrong result]

and this is what I expect (hanging number, paragraphs with no indentation at first line):

[image: expected result]

By the way, I also don't want the numbering (in the footnote) to be typeset in superscript, the footnote should look like:

```
1.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
      adipiscing elit. (...)
```

But this is another question.

Comment: I get hanging footnote in a current texlive.

Comment: Oh, then it's a version problem again...

Comment: if you have an older system, try with babel. Its french module is more sophisticated anyway.